# Is there a simple way in Ruby to get the terminal output?

Tags: ruby, watir

I’m running tests using Watir and certain results get posted to the terminal for convenience by using puts or print.

Is there a way of extracting or dumping the terminal output somewhere if for example I wanted to store it or send it in an email?

Comment: The duplicate talks about `$stderr` but the answer is completely analogous for `$stdout`: divert it to a `StringIO`.